# Regex for 8 digit number beginning with two similar numbers?

Tags: regex, string, matching

I would like to validate 8 digit phone numbers that start with a double digit greater than 2.
eg: 33452334 would validate while 32222222 would not.
This is what I tried but it's not working since it doesn't make sure the two first digits are similar:

```
^[3-9]{2}\d{6}$
```

Comment: Why `32222222` wouldn't?

Comment: @AvinashRaj "double digit".

Comment: @FredrikPihl My answer is based on ECMAScript, the common standard for most notations. Can you think of a flavor-specific solution for this case?

Comment: In this case no, but generally speaking, answering regexp questions is much easier when flavor is known.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use this regex:

```
^([3-9])\1\d{6}$
```

- `( )` to capture,
- `\1` to use a back reference.